# RactiveJS and jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, plugins, ractivejs

I have a form with multiple fields, some of them being for plain text and some of them require plugins for advanced select and upload capability.

There are 2 problems with this:

- ractive needs to parse the template and render it before I can attach the plugins so there is some small delay
- the second one is that such plugins change the markup around mentioned fields and that cannot work with ractive's generated DOM tree because that markup is out of 
  sync.

What is the right approach to solving this problem? I would really like to use ractive for binding all form values and controlling behaviour of it all but at this point it seems nearly impossible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A good way to integrate jQuery plugins with Ractive is to use [decorators](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/writing-decorator-plugins). A decorator is a function that gets called when an element enters the DOM; it returns an object with a `teardown()` method that is called when it's removed from the DOM.

So if you were using the [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin, your decorator might look like this:

```
var fileupload = function (node) {
  $(node).fileupload();

  return {
    teardown: function () {
      $(node).fileupload('destroy');
    }
  };
};
```

Once you've created the decorator, you need to *register* it. The easiest way is to make it globally available...

```
Ractive.decorators.fileupload = fileupload;
```

...but you can also pass in per-instance or per-component decorators:

```
// instance will have the fileupload decorator
ractive = new Ractive({
  // ...usual options...
  decorators: { fileupload: fileupload }
});

// all instances of Widget will have the decorator
Widget = Ractive.extend({
  decorators: { fileupload: fileupload }
});
```

Then, you can use it in your template like so:

```
<input decorator="fileupload" type="file" data-url="whatever">
```

It so happens that with this plugin you can specify options with `data-` attributes. But if you needed to specify options via the decorator itself, you could do so:

```
<input decorator="fileupload:{{url}},{multiple:true}" type="file">
```

In this example, the decorator function would receive two additional arguments - a URL, and an options object:

```
Ractive.decorators.fileupload = function (node, url, options) {
  // setup code...

  return {
    update: function (url, options) {
      // if the options change (i.e. `url` updates),
      // this function is called
    },
    teardown: function () {
      // teardown code...
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Rich thank you very much for this clear and concise explanation. Exactly the the stuff I was hoping to find. This helped me a lot.

Comment: This just helped me out with jquery UI tabs (can't quite work out how to make an Ractive component for them) and accordion controls. Nice one!

Comment: This helped me out no end when writing a sortable plugin. I just wrapped jquery sortable. However, I have one question... probably need to make a new post - I'm not sure...